# iScroll 5 is not smooth on windows phone 8

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, iscroll, iscroll4

Scrolling with iScroll on windows phone 8 shows strange behaviour. I can scroll by probably 10-15 px only. As if it starts and then stops suddenly. `onScrollStart` event is fired but `onScrollEnd` is not. Looks like it is related to js but I do not see any console errors. Did anyone have issues like this? On iPhone and Android all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding on parent element `-ms-touch-action: none;`

Comment: adding it where? to parent element? to inner div that scrolls? (-:

Comment: @TerraElise on parent element.